# how can i deploy my web application asp.net mvc 5 using visual studio 2015 !?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

i have developed a few applications in MVC 5 , but never really got a chance to learn about  deployment to server of   our company . It was handled by our seniors. So I have very less ...please help me and tell me what i do step by step

Comment: Step 1- read the VS documentation about web deploy, Step 2- deploy your app.

Comment: waaaw thx for advice .....-__-

Comment: Your question is very broad, as it doesn't give any details as to where exactly your applications are being deployed to (Azure, own IIS server etc). Please can you elaborate?

Comment: Yep, it's pretty broad, as Geoff says.

In all honesty, your best bet is probably to talk to your seniors and see if they'll walk you through it in your environment - maybe ask if you can shadow them on the next deployment. Once you have (some of) their expertise to show you on your environment, you can start trying to translate that to other deployments.